# Locally Filtered Data is not coming in the alert Box in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Thanx To Oleg From where I have added code to get the particular column data in the Jqgrid on filtering the records locally , but it is not showing the data filtered in the alert box . In the alert box  it is showing total number of data and empty string for the data values ...
Here is my code...

```
 var oldFrom = $.jgrid.from, lastSelected;

            $.jgrid.from = function (source, initalQuery) {
                var result = oldFrom.call(this, source, initalQuery),
                old_select = result.select;
                result.select = function (f) {
                    lastSelected = old_select.call(this, f);
                    return lastSelected;
                };
                return result;
            };
```

Here I am loading in the JqGrid...

```
loadComplete: function () {
                            this.p.lastSelected = lastSelected;
                        }
```

Below is my Button click function ...

```
 $("#go").click(function () {
                        var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelected'), i, n, ids = [],
                idName = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'localReader').price;
                        if (filteredData) {
                            for (i = 0, n = filteredData.length; i < n; i++) {
                                ids.push(filteredData[i][idName]);
                            }
                            alert("tolal number of filtered data: " + n + "\n" +
                    "ids of filtered data:\n" + ids.join(', '));
                        }
                    });
```

Here i Want to took out the values of price column which i have added in the grid ..

```
 { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center',formatter: 'currency' }
```

.Plz GuysHelp me ..
Thanx in advance...